# Go net.DialUDP auto-selecting loopback interface

Tags: go, udp

I have a need to send some UDP packets from eth0 on a host to itself, also on eth0.

I have some working Go code, but it appears to be using the loopback interface instead of eth0 as expected.

```
package main

import (
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ip := net.ParseIP("192.168.1.158")

    src := net.UDPAddr{IP: ip, Port: 8888,}
    dest := net.UDPAddr{IP: ip, Port: 88}

    conn, _ := net.DialUDP("udp", &src, &dest)

    conn.Write([]byte("hi"))
}
```

192.168.1.158 is the primary and only IP address for the interface on my machine.

Running the following command shows me the traffic:

```
sudo tcpdump udp -v -i lo
```

However, I would expect the traffic be to/from the system interface with the IP address I've defined.

Am I missing a step here?

I have also tried this slightly different approach, but with the same results:

```
src, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "192.168.1.158:8888")
dest, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "192.168.1.158:88")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I would expect the traffic be to/from the system interface with the IP address I've defined.

This is simply the wrong expectation and unrelated to Go.

Just try `ping 192.168.1.158` and check with `tcpdump -i lo -n icmp` vs. `tcpdump -i eth0 -n icmp` where the data actually gets transferred. You will see that the packets are transferred on the `lo` interface. Similar a `ip route get 192.168.1.158` will show you that the route to your local address goes through the `lo` interface.

Comment: Interesting, yes I see what you are saying.

I'm doing something similar in Python with scapy and I see the traffic on the target interface as I expected. I've been trying to re-create this behaviour in Go without any luck.

However, the scapy stuff is more at the raw packet level. Looks like I need to look deeper and/or ask better questions.

Will mark as resolved, thanks for taking the time to answer!